# Asymptotic behavior of n'th derivative

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I have a function $f(x)$ which is defined around $x=0$. I would like to understand the asymptotic behavior of its $n$'th derivative $f^{(n)}(0)$ evaluated at zero as $n \to \infty$. Is there any trick to derive it? In case that question is too general, maybe you could help me out with my specific function, which is given by:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-xe^{-\alpha(1-x)}},$$
where $\alpha$ is a parameter. For this function the $n$'th derivative should scale as $f^{(n)}(0) \sim \frac{c}{n!}$, where $c$ is some constant depending on $\alpha$.

Comment: https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/amm/lecture05.pdf - page 18; 5. 2. Example: The binomial coefficient. This is also how to find the asymptotics of higher derivatives $n\to\infty$ . The $n$th derivative of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ can be represented as  $\oint \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$, and then the Laplace method can be applied

Comment: For $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$, and $f^{(n)}(0)=n!$
For $g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-xe^{-\alpha(1-x)}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k(1-e^{-\alpha k(1-x)})$. It seems that the main asymptotics term of $g^{(n)}(0)$ is also $\sim n!$ and does not depend on $\alpha$ (if $\alpha>0)$.

Comment: The approach using contour integration seems interesting. Thanks alot, I will try it out.

Comment: For meromorphic functions, the asymptotics will be determined by the distance to the nearest pole (see *generatingfunctionology* by Wilf), so
$$[x^n] \frac 1 {1 - x e^{-\alpha (1 - x)}} \sim
\frac 1 {1 + W(\alpha e^\alpha)} \left(
 \frac \alpha {W(\alpha e^\alpha)} \right)^{\! n}$$
for $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \{-1\}$ and $n \to \infty$, where $\sim$ means asymptotic equivalence and $W$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W-function. $W(\alpha e^\alpha) = \alpha$ for $\alpha > -1$.

Comment: Thanks alot Maxim: It took me a while to get through Wilf's book. That method is really amazing.